# What does setting a certificate authority cert within an application do?

Tags: elasticsearch, certificate, kibana

When an application optionally allows you to specify a certificate which represents a certificate authority, what is that doing?

Does that basically set that cert as a "trusted" certificate?

Specific example:

Kibana communicates with elasticsearch.  When you configure kibana, you can set the following configuration value:

```
elasticsearch.ssl.ca
```

The documentation says this value is an "Optional setting that enables you to specify a path to the PEM file for the certificate authority for your Elasticsearch instance." ([source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/kibana-server-properties.html))

Within that same config you're also specifying a certificate and key that can be used for communication with the elasticsearch instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the setting is optional it means that the default behaviour is to use the system Root CAs to validate the SSL Server certificate used by your Elasticsearch instance. If you used a standard commercial SSL Server certificate this should be enough.

Yes, you are setting that certificate as a Root CA but only for this application.

Using the setting you can specify the Root CA used to generated the SSL Server certificate. This is useful if you:

- use a selfsigned certificate
- use a Root CA that is not available in the system Root CA repository
- need to have stringent security settings limiting subset of Root CAs trusted by your application.